# Using corn-cps to scan for config files matching wildcard pattern

Tags: java

I'm trying to scan my classpath for config files matching a certain pattern. I'm using [corn-cps](https://sites.google.com/site/javacornproject/corn-cps).

The file I'm looking for is packaged in a jar and I can find it using java's default

```
MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("jmulticonfig.3.properties")
```

returns

```
jar:file:/tmp/testjar.jar!/jmulticonfig.3.properties
```

I would like to find all jmulticonfig.*.properties so my corn-cps code is

```
List<URL> resources = CPScanner.scanResources(
      new ResourceFilter()
        .packageName("*")
          .resourceName("jmulticonfig.*.properties")
      );
```

An empty List is returned when I run this.

Anyone with corn-cps experience can help or suggest some other way?

Edit: To take the good suggestion of @approxiblue, the code can be found at https://github.com/kanesee/jmulticonfig.
Please make sure to add src/main/resources/jmulticonfig-3.jar to your classpath. It contains jmulticonfig.3.properties, the file which I'm trying to read using corn-cps

Comment: Your code works fine when I run it with corn-cps-1.1.7... Can you double check that your classpath contains all the jars with `jmulticonfig.*.properties` files when you run the CPScanner program.

Comment: I believe it is in the classpath. In the same code, I run ...getClassLoader().getResource("...") and it finds the file. Your file is packaged inside a jar that you add to the classpath too?

Comment: I tried with both files on the disk and files packaged inside a jar.

Comment: You should post the structure of your jar, the location of MyClass and the code snippet, etc.

Comment: @approxiblue github code has been included. good suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've found some kind of bug in the corn-cps library because if you debug their classes running your code, it seems that there is a point where the resource name gets lost.

Anyway the following JmultiConfig.getConfig() implementation finds all the resources you're searching with a regular expression:

```
public static synchronized Properties getConfig() {
    System.out.println("---");
    if (s_props == null) {
        List<URL> resources = CPScanner.scanResources(new ResourceFilter().archiveName("*"));
        for (URL resource : resources) {
            if (resource.getFile().matches(".*jmulticonfig\\..*\\.properties$")) {
                System.out.println("*** -> " + resource);
            }
        }

    }
    return s_props;
}
```

The regular expression can be modified to match anything you need.

Comment: It seems you are right. Your workaround is good enough for me though may not be what the original corn-cps author intended. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to obtain resources from the default package `""`.

But `corn-cps` has a **bug** reading resources from that package (the condition in line 63 of `net.sf.corn.cps.RootedUrl` fails for these resources).

For a workaround you could place your resources in another package, e.g. package `res` and filter for that package:

```
List<URL> resources = CPScanner.scanResources(
    new ResourceFilter().packageName("res").resourceName("jmulticonfig.*.properties")
  );
```

Also a filter `.packageName(*)` finds resources in all packages, except the default package.

---

The solution a Max also works, but comes at the price to construct a URL object for every resource in the classpath (except rt.jar which is not covered by corn-cps).

Comment: I've tried packageName("me.kanesee"), packageName("*"), packageName("") and leaving out the packageName() call altogether. If you can find a combination that works, please let me know

Comment: This is a good solution too. Unfortunately, this requires the properties files to be located under some package and I don't know if I want to require that. Thanks for the solution though. It may be better for others